# &> test or > test 2>&1

Tags: bash

I read from an instruction using `&>` to handle errors and data

```
$ls -al test test2 test3 badtest &> test7
$ cat test7
ls: cannot access 'test': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'badtest': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 me staff 78 Oct 28 19:07 test2
-rw-r--r-- 1 me staff  0 Oct 28 19:03 test3
```

Nonetheless, when I check [Obsolete and deprecated syntax [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)

It recommends `2>&1`

```
$ ls -al test test2 test3 badtest > test7 2>&1

 $ cat test7
ls: cannot access 'test': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'badtest': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 me staff 78 Oct 28 19:07 test2
-rw-r--r-- 1 me staff  0 Oct 28 19:03 test3
```

Which pattern should I follow

Comment: The title of that page is highly misleading... AFAIK the `&>` is **not** deprecated in bash. The title should be something like *Non-POSIX syntaxes and their POSIX equivalent*. The term "deprecation" would imply that some future version of bash will remove that syntax, but that is not the case (as far as I know, for now at least). FYI: looking at `man bash` it mentions only one deprecated syntax: `$[expression]`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, the page has different sections, and it clearly/explicitly describes which is which.

Comment: See also [Why does 'nohup command >& /dev/null' seem to "work" in some shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/118303)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is up to you to decide.

The `bash` shell understands `&>file` and `>file 2>&1` as identical and you may use the former syntax as a shortcut way of writing the latter.  Other shells may throw a syntax error or do something unexpected with `&>`.

If you *only* write `bash` scripts (and not scripts for e.g. `/bin/sh`), then by all means use `&>`, but if you find yourself wanting or needing to write *portable* scripts (scripts that need to run under `/bin/sh` or that should be executable by any `sh`-like shell, of which `bash` is one and `ksh`, `zsh` and `dash` are others), then `&>` is one of the things you should avoid.

All `sh`-like shells implement [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html) in terms of syntax and grammar, but `bash` and other shells also provides syntactic conveniences like `&>` and extensions like arrays and regular expression matching etc., and some shells may expand on the POSIX standard quite differently from the way `bash` is doing it.

Related:

- [Other questions on this site about `bash` and portability](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+portability+site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com) (DuckDuckGo search link).

Comment: except that this particular "feature" is not just an extension, because it's incompatible with POSIX, as it is clearly explained in the link from the OP's question: "They also introduce parsing ambiguity, and **conflict with POSIX**. Shells without this feature treat cmd1 &>file cmd2 as: "background cmd1 and then execute cmd2 with its stdout redirected to file", **which is the correct interpretation of this expression**". The fact that other shells will silently interpret this to something else *in accordance with the standard* makes pretty obvious that this syntax should NOT be used, ever.

Comment: @mosvy From a POSIX point of view, that would definitely be the correct interpretation, yes.